# How to achieve that blur effect do not affect my buttons on navigation bar CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to achieve that blur effect do not affect my buttons on navigation bar....

I want to blur only green color where i will add gradient effect and i want that my list on navigation bar (about, services, portfolio, pricing, contact) stay clear white color.

Please help me...

```css
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #00A1A6;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  filter: blur (5px);
}

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #00A1A6 !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
  <div class="wrapper-parallax">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use pseudo class `:before` for the `background` on `.navbar` class and then apply `filter:blur(5px)` to `:before`

```
.navbar.navbar-default:before {
  content: "";
  filter: blur(5px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #00A1A6;
  display: block;
}
```

**[Fiddle Link ▸](https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/oopu398d/5/)**

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar.navbar-default:before {
  content: "";
  filter: blur(5px);
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  background: #00A1A6;
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #00A1A6 !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a {}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-parallax">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know how i can make edges sharp?

Comment: @JosipPavlović try to change position values of `:before` to negative values...Updated!